# Get desired Module and add artifacts in it using OSCL + JAVA

Tags: ibm-doors, oslc

I am new at OSLC + JAVA framework. Currently I am trying to add some artifacts in particular module.

So I need to fetch that module and add new artifact in it.

As a part of POC currently I am able to add base  artifact in some folder by setting that folder path as parent.

Is there any resource available to add artifact in particular module ?

It will be really helpful if we get some sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting answer here for the OLSC user :

```
package csvImport.poc;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

import org.apache.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.wink.client.ClientResponse;
import org.eclipse.lyo.client.exception.RootServicesException;
import org.eclipse.lyo.client.oslc.OSLCConstants;
import org.eclipse.lyo.client.oslc.jazz.JazzFormAuthClient;
import org.eclipse.lyo.client.oslc.jazz.JazzRootServicesHelper;
import org.eclipse.lyo.client.oslc.resources.OslcQuery;
import org.eclipse.lyo.client.oslc.resources.OslcQueryParameters;
import org.eclipse.lyo.client.oslc.resources.OslcQueryResult;
import org.eclipse.lyo.client.oslc.resources.Requirement;
import org.eclipse.lyo.client.oslc.resources.RequirementCollection;
import org.eclipse.lyo.client.oslc.resources.RmUtil;
import org.eclipse.lyo.oslc4j.core.model.OslcMediaType;
import org.eclipse.lyo.oslc4j.core.model.ResourceShape;

import net.oauth.OAuthException;

public class OSLCHelper {

    String user;
    String pwd;
    String projectArea;
    String serverUrl;

    String catalogUrl;
    String serviceProviderUrl;
    String queryCapability;
    String requirementFactory;

    private static JazzRootServicesHelper rootServicesHelper = null;
    private static JazzFormAuthClient client = null;

    public boolean logIn() throws Exception {
        if (client.login() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public OSLCHelper(String user, String pwd, String projectArea, String serverUrl) {
        this.user = user;
        this.pwd = pwd;
        this.projectArea = projectArea;
        this.serverUrl = serverUrl;
        try {
            rootServicesHelper = new JazzRootServicesHelper(serverUrl, OSLCConstants.OSLC_RM_V2);
        } catch (RootServicesException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        client = rootServicesHelper.initFormClient(user, pwd);
    }

    public void updateURLs() throws Exception {
        // STEP 4: Get the URL of the OSLC ChangeManagement catalog
        catalogUrl = rootServicesHelper.getCatalogUrl();

        // STEP 5: Find the OSLC Service Prsovider for the project area we want to work
        // with
        serviceProviderUrl = client.lookupServiceProviderUrl(catalogUrl, projectArea);

        // STEP 6: Get the Query Capabilities URL so that we can run some OSLC queries
        queryCapability = client.lookupQueryCapability(serviceProviderUrl, OSLCConstants.OSLC_RM_V2,
                OSLCConstants.RM_REQUIREMENT_TYPE);
        // STEP 7: Create base requirements
        // Get the Creation Factory URL for change requests so that we can create one

        requirementFactory = client.lookupCreationFactory(serviceProviderUrl, OSLCConstants.OSLC_RM_V2,
                OSLCConstants.RM_REQUIREMENT_TYPE);
    }

    public String[] getAllRequirementURLS() {
        OslcQueryParameters queryParams = new OslcQueryParameters();
        queryParams.setPrefix("rdf=<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>");
        queryParams.setWhere("rdf:type=<http://open-services.net/ns/rm#Requirement>");
        OslcQuery query = new OslcQuery(client, queryCapability, 10, queryParams);
        OslcQueryResult result = query.submit();
        for (String iterable_element : result.getMembersUrls()) {
            System.out.println(iterable_element);
        }
        return result.getMembersUrls();
    }
    public String[] getAllRequirementCollectionsURLS() {
        OslcQueryParameters queryParams = new OslcQueryParameters();
        queryParams.setPrefix("rdf=<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>");
        queryParams.setWhere("rdf:type=<http://open-services.net/ns/rm#RequirementCollection>");
        OslcQuery query = new OslcQuery(client, queryCapability, 10, queryParams);
        OslcQueryResult result = query.submit();
        for (String iterable_element : result.getMembersUrls()) {
            System.out.println(iterable_element);
        }
        return result.getMembersUrls();
    }

    public String getRequirementById(String id) {
        OslcQueryParameters queryParams = new OslcQueryParameters();
        String url = "";
        queryParams.setPrefix("dcterms=<http://purl.org/dc/terms/>");
        queryParams.setWhere("dcterms:identifier="+id);
        OslcQuery query = new OslcQuery(client, queryCapability, 10, queryParams);
        OslcQueryResult result = query.submit();
        String[] membersUrls = result.getMembersUrls();
        if (membersUrls.length>0) {
            url = membersUrls[0];
        }
        return url ;
    }

    public String createRequirement(String requirementType, String title, String description) throws Exception {
        // Get Feature Requirement Type URL
        
        serviceProviderUrl = client.lookupServiceProviderUrl(catalogUrl, projectArea);

        // STEP 6: Get the Query Capabilities URL so that we can run some OSLC queries
        queryCapability = client.lookupQueryCapability(serviceProviderUrl, OSLCConstants.OSLC_RM_V2,
                OSLCConstants.RM_REQUIREMENT_TYPE);
        // STEP 7: Create base requirements
        // Get the Creation Factory URL for change requests so that we can create one

        requirementFactory = client.lookupCreationFactory(serviceProviderUrl, OSLCConstants.OSLC_RM_V2,
                OSLCConstants.RM_REQUIREMENT_TYPE);
        
        ResourceShape featureInstanceShape = RmUtil.lookupRequirementsInstanceShapes(serviceProviderUrl,
                OSLCConstants.OSLC_RM_V2, OSLCConstants.RM_REQUIREMENT_TYPE, client, requirementType);
        Requirement requirement = new Requirement();
        requirement.setInstanceShape(featureInstanceShape.getAbout());
        requirement.setTitle(title);
        requirement.setDescription(description);
        // Create the Requirement
        ClientResponse creationResponse = client.createResource(requirementFactory, requirement,
                OslcMediaType.APPLICATION_RDF_XML, OslcMediaType.APPLICATION_RDF_XML);
        String req04URL = creationResponse.getHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.LOCATION);
        creationResponse.consumeContent();
        return req04URL;
    }

    public boolean createRequirementCollection(String requirementType, String title, String description)
            throws Exception {
        // Get Feature Requirement Type URL
        boolean isAdded = true;

        ResourceShape collectionInstanceShape = RmUtil.lookupRequirementsInstanceShapes(serviceProviderUrl,
                OSLCConstants.OSLC_RM_V2, OSLCConstants.RM_REQUIREMENT_COLLECTION_TYPE, client,
                "Diagnostics Specification");
        RequirementCollection collection = new RequirementCollection();
//      collection.addUses(new URI(req04URL));
        collection.setInstanceShape(collectionInstanceShape.getAbout());
        collection.setTitle("All DTCs");
        collection.setDescription("Created By EclipseLyo");
        // Create the collection
        ClientResponse creationResponse = client.createResource(requirementFactory, collection,
                OslcMediaType.APPLICATION_RDF_XML, OslcMediaType.APPLICATION_RDF_XML);
        creationResponse.consumeContent();

        String reqcoll01URL = creationResponse.getHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.LOCATION);
        creationResponse.consumeContent();
        if (reqcoll01URL != null) {
            isAdded = false;
        }
        return isAdded;
    }
    
    public Requirement updateRequirement(Map<String,Object> dataMap , String url) throws Exception{
        boolean isUpdated=false;
        ClientResponse getResponse = client.getResource(url,OslcMediaType.APPLICATION_RDF_XML);
        Requirement requirement = getResponse.getEntity(Requirement.class);
        // Get the eTAG, we need it to update
        String etag = getResponse.getHeaders().getFirst(OSLCConstants.ETAG);
        getResponse.consumeContent();
        Map<QName, Object> extendedProperties = requirement.getExtendedProperties();
        Map<QName, Object> removeCurrentProperty = new HashMap<QName, Object>(extendedProperties); 
        for (Entry<String, Object> entry : dataMap.entrySet()) {
            String qName = entry.getKey();
            Object value = entry.getValue();
            removeCurrentProperty = removeCurrentProperty(removeCurrentProperty,qName);
            removeCurrentProperty.put(new QName(qName), value);
            requirement.setExtendedProperties(removeCurrentProperty);
        }
        // Update the requirement with the proper etag
        ClientResponse updateResponse = client.updateResource(url,
                requirement, OslcMediaType.APPLICATION_RDF_XML, OslcMediaType.APPLICATION_RDF_XML, etag);
        updateResponse.consumeContent();
        if (updateResponse.getStatusCode()==200) {
            isUpdated=true;
        }
        
        return requirement;
    }
    
    private Map<QName, Object> removeCurrentProperty(Map<QName, Object> extendedProperties, String qName) {
        String comapre = qName.substring(qName.lastIndexOf("/") + 1).trim();
        Map<QName, Object> returnMap= new HashMap<QName, Object>(extendedProperties);
        for (Entry<QName, Object> entry : extendedProperties.entrySet()) {
            QName key = entry.getKey();
            if (key.getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase(comapre)) {
                returnMap.remove(key);
            }
            
        }
        return returnMap;
    }

    public Requirement getRequirementByUrl(String url) throws Exception {
        ClientResponse getResponse = null;
        Requirement requirement =null;
        if (url!=null) {
            getResponse = client.getResource(url,OslcMediaType.APPLICATION_RDF_XML);
            requirement = getResponse.getEntity(Requirement.class);
        }
        return requirement;
    }
    
    public RequirementCollection getRequirementCollectionByUrl(String url) throws Exception {
        ClientResponse getResponse = null;
        RequirementCollection requirement =null;
        if (url!=null) {
            getResponse = client.getResource(url,OslcMediaType.APPLICATION_RDF_XML);
            requirement = getResponse.getEntity(RequirementCollection.class);
        }
        return requirement;
    }
    


    public String getRequirementCollectionByTitle(String title) {
        OslcQueryParameters queryParams = new OslcQueryParameters();
        String url = "";
        queryParams.setPrefix("dcterms=<http://purl.org/dc/terms/>");
        queryParams.setWhere("dcterms:title=\""+title+"\"");
        OslcQuery query = new OslcQuery(client, queryCapability, 10, queryParams);
        OslcQueryResult result = query.submit();
        String[] membersUrls = result.getMembersUrls();
        if (membersUrls.length>0) {
            url = membersUrls[0];
        }
        return url ;
    }
    private String getRequirementCollectionByIdentifier(String id) {
        OslcQueryParameters queryParams = new OslcQueryParameters();
        String url = "";
        queryParams.setPrefix("dcterms=<http://purl.org/dc/terms/>");
        queryParams.setWhere("dcterms:identifier="+id);
        OslcQuery query = new OslcQuery(client, queryCapability, 10, queryParams);
        OslcQueryResult result = query.submit();
        String[] membersUrls = result.getMembersUrls();
        if (membersUrls.length>0) {
            url = membersUrls[0];
        }
        return url ;
    }

    public void updateSpecificRequirementCollectionWithRequiremtns(List<Requirement> requiremtns, String title) throws Exception {
        String url = getRequirementCollectionByTitle(title);
        ClientResponse getResponse = null;
        RequirementCollection requirement =null;
        if (url!=null) {
                getResponse = client.getResource(url,OslcMediaType.APPLICATION_RDF_XML);
            String etag = getResponse.getHeaders().getFirst(OSLCConstants.ETAG);
            requirement = getResponse.getEntity(RequirementCollection.class);
            if (requirement!=null) {
                for (Requirement requirement2 : requiremtns) {
                    requirement.addUses(new  URI(requirement2.getAbout().toString()));
                    break;
                }
            }
            ClientResponse updateResponse = client.updateResource(requirement.getAbout().toString(),
                    requirement, OslcMediaType.APPLICATION_RDF_XML, OslcMediaType.APPLICATION_RDF_XML, etag);
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
    
     

}
```